# Focusing on Popper activated on MouseOver

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a `Popper` activated on mouseOver and deactivated on mouseOut).

My popper contains a link for a user to click on.

The problem is that as soon as I move out of the popper, it disappears and I cannot figure out a way to keep it open for a user to click a link.

The [simplified code](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-forest-rv4g2x) is below:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, Popper } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  const [el, setEl] = useState<(EventTarget & Element) | null>(null);
  const [inBox, setBox] = useState(false);
  const handle1 = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (inBox) return;
    console.log("enter");
    setEl(e.currentTarget);
  };

  const handle2 = () => {
    if (inBox) return;
    console.log("close");
    setEl(null);
  };

  const open = !!el;

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box
        component="div"
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: "red",
          width: "100px",
          height: "100px"
        }}
        onMouseOver={(e) => handle1(e)}
        onMouseOut={handle2}
      />
      {open && (
        <Popper open={open} anchorEl={el} placement="bottom-start">
          <Box
            sx={{
              backgroundColor: "green",
              width: "170px",
              height: "70px"
            }}
            onMouseOver={() => {
              console.log("ENTERING");
              setBox(true);
            }}
            onMouseOut={() => {
              setBox(false);
            }}
          />
        </Popper>
      )}
      <Box
        onMouseEnter={handle1}
        onMouseLeave={handle2}
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: "blue",
          width: "100px",
          height: "100px"
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't perfectly understand what you want. But, I guess you want to do that mouseover at popper show Box & mouseout on Box disappear box? Right?

```
import React, { useRef, RefObject, useEffect } from "react";

const Popper = () => {

const divEl1 = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
const divEl2 = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
const [isOver,setIsOver] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const { current } = divEl1;
    if(current) {
        current.addEventListener("mouseover", () =>  setIsOver(true));
        current.removeEventListener("mouseover", () => setIsOver(true));
    }
}, [divEl1]);

useEffect(() => {
    const { current } = divEl2;
    if(current) {
        current.addEventListener("mouseout", () =>  setIsOver(false));
        current.removeEventListener("mouseout", () => setIsOver(false));
    }
}, [divEl2]);

return (
    <div >
        <div ref={divEl1 as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}>
            Popper
        </div>
        <div style={{display : isOver ? "block" : "none"}} ref={divEl2 as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}>
              Show/NotShow
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Thanks - not exactly what I wanted, but it is a good solution for mouseOver popper